# Constructing every pair of two square numbers with fixed sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares, combinatorial-number-theory

Let $s\in\mathbb{N}$ have the prime factorization $s=2^gp_1^{f_1}p_2^{f_2}\dots q_1^{h_1}q_2^{h_2}\dots$, where $p_i \equiv 1$ and $q_i \equiv 3$ (mod 4). I already know how many distinct $(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ with $a^2+b^2=s$ exist: If every $h_i$ is even, then there are $(f_1+1)(f_2+1)\dots$, but if one $h_i$ is odd, then there are 0. How do I construct every $(a,b)$, however?

Comment: I believe there is something about factoring the $p_i$ into Gaussian primes and then allocating factors accordingly? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY talks about it.

Comment: Note that  we may divide out by any  power of 4  or any power of  any $q_i^2$  As each $p_i =  u_i^2 + v_i^2$   we may.....

Comment: If $u=a^2+b^2$ and $v=c^2+d^2$ then $uv=(|ac-bd|)^2+(ad+bc)^2=(ac+bd)^2+(|ad-bc|)^2.$